# method call interception in scala

Tags: scala, reflection, method-invocation, method-interception

Hi I was wondering if there is a way to reflectively (or otherwise) intercept all method calls send to a class. I know that unknown methods can be intercepted using Dynamic, but how about methods already defined in the class?

I would like to find a way to do it without having to modify the syntax of methods (as it is done to intercept methods in the aspects framework).

As an example of what I would like to do imagine this:

```
class A extends AProxy {
  def foo = 
    println("do something")
}

class AProxy extends Dynamic {
  def captureKnownMethods = {
    //Capture all methods defined in A
}

def applyDynamic(args) = {
  //Capture unknown methods
}
```

}

```
A myclass = new A
myclass.foo   //method call captured by captureKnownMethods
myclass.bar   //method call captured by applyDynamic
```

Comment: see Scala Macwire https://github.com/softwaremill/macwire#interceptors